# Do I need to add android.support.v8.renderscript to my build path in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, renderscript

I'm trying to create new Android application that run's on API-16.
I've set the target SDK as API-19, and the minimum SDK level to API-16.

My project.properties file contain the following lines:

`target=android-19
renderscript.target=19
renderscript.support.mode=true
sdk.buildtools=19`

However, the  android.support.v8.renderscript package is not visible to my code. to I need to add it explicitly?

Thanks,

Ziv

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have an answer yet, I think you don't have to use a support library because API 16 supports `android.renderscript.*`. Delete these lines `renderscript.target=19 renderscript.support.mode=true sdk.buildtools=19` and simply use `android.renderscript.*`.